# createCameraPreviewSession: Surface had no valid native window - error on second creation

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, android-camera2

We call from Ionic a custom Cordova plugin which uses the Camera2 API to capture a frame. On the second call of this plugin within Ionic (which follows subsequently) we get **sometimes** (like in one out of ten cases) the following error:

```
2019-01-14 18:08:16.471 31738-31738/io.ionic.starter E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: getNativeWindow: Surface had no valid native window.
2019-01-14 18:08:16.472 31738-31738/io.ionic.starter E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: LegacyCameraDevice_nativeDetectSurfaceDimens: Could not retrieve native window from surface.
2019-01-14 18:08:16.472 31738-31738/io.ionic.starter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-01-14 18:08:16.472 31738-31738/io.ionic.starter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.ionic.starter, PID: 31738
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown error -22
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils.throwOnError(LegacyExceptionUtils.java:77)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceSize(LegacyCameraDevice.java:583)
        at android.hardware.camera2.utils.SurfaceUtils.getSurfaceSize(SurfaceUtils.java:68)
        at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init>(OutputConfiguration.java:237)
        at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init>(OutputConfiguration.java:101)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:499)

        at dev.capture.Camera2Scanner.createCameraPreviewSession(Camera2Scanner.java:675)
        at dev.capture.Camera2Scanner.access$200(Camera2Scanner.java:47)
        at dev.capture.Camera2Scanner$2.onOpened(Camera2Scanner.java:191)

        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:139)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

So I checked the Android JNI sources for this error, there it says that this error is thrown when **getNativeWindow()** returns null. But what extactly does this function do and what does this mean for our surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've passed in a Surface to CameraDevice.createCaptureSession that's no longer valid; generally that's because whatever you got the Surface from has been either garbage collected, or because the UI element it draws to is no longer valid.

So if a SurfaceView is not valid to draw to any more, or an ImageReader has been released, etc, you can get this error.  You need to sort out which Surface is invalid, and then figure out why its source is no longer in good shape.

Comment: May it be possible that this error occurs, when we try to open the camera view while there is a second Cordova plugin running in the background and processing the first captured image? Because I could resolve this issue by splitting them apart and run one after another.

Comment: If they share a preview View, that's certainly possible, but it would depend on how it's all wired together.

Comment: for me this issue only happens for devices with legacy camera when using Camera2 API. If using camera legacy api for legacy devices than everything is ok... so basically Camera2 API may not be stable for devices with legacy camera

Comment: and if you pass not valid surface to `CameraDevice.createCaptureSession` then it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Surface was abandoned` exception directly in your code and I have `try...catch` for this case but exception from the question happens in camera2 API itself and we are not able tp catch it, it happens only for Legacy camera when using camera2 api with such devices